# Overwriding Equality Test in Integer Wrapper Class

Tags: python, class, integer, wrapper, equality

Let's say I made an integer wrapper class in Python, like Java has. Most of the methods would be pretty trivial. But the **__ eq __** overload (the equality test) poses a fun puzzle: consider the following method

```
def __eq__( self, other ):
    return self.value == int(other)
```

**Implementation details:**

- The Integer Wrapper has one field, "value," which is an integer
- The method **__ trunc __** returns the field "value" so that int( Integer(x) ) = x
- The constructor for Integer truncates "value" to an integer; Integer(3.1)=Integer(3)

**Rules for the Method**

1. Integer(x) == Integer(x) must return true for all integers x
2. Integer(x) == x must return true for all integers x
3. Integer(x) == Integer(y) must return false for all inegers (x,y) such that x != y
4. Integer(x) == y must return false for all x != y

My beautiful method can be susceptible to the very last test. Consider

```
Integer(1) == 1.1
```

Will return true.

How can we implement an Integer class under the stated constraints - something that seems trivial, with the stated fairly straight-forward definition of equality?

Note: you might find it bothersome that I claim Integer(1.1) == Integer(1) is a valid result. I'll admit it has some silliness to it, but I have control over how the constructor handles non-integer parameters; I could throw an exception if I wanted claiming unsafe cast. I don't have any control over the fourth case, in which someone asks if my integer equals a primitive of the same value.

**Edit**
Per request, here's enough code for the class that I think the conditions I've set forth are satisfied:

```
class Integer:
  """ An integer wrapper class. Provides support for using integers as
      objects. There are subtelties and pitfalls, however. """

 def __init__( self, val = 0 ):
    """ Constructs a new integer with a certain value """
    self.val = int(val)

 def __trunc__( self ):
 """ Truncates the internal value """
 return int(self.val)

 def __eq__( self, other ):
 """ Returns true if the object ahs the same value as this object """
 return self.val == int(other)
```

Comment: You sir have an interesting question :D. Can you post the rest of your code - i think I know a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your requirements correctly, this should do it:

```
>>> class Integer:
...   def __init__(self, val=0):
...     self.val = int(val)
...   def __eq__(self, other):
...     return self.val == other
... 
>>> Integer(1) == 1.1
False
>>> Integer(1.2) == Integer(1.3)
True
>>> Integer(4) == Integer(7)
False
>>> Integer(2) == 2
True
>>>
```

Comment: that does seem to do it.. thought this was trickier than it was

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the issue here is that the value you compare against might be a float, rather than an int, that, in return, would get truncated to an equal int, if compared against.

If that is the case how about checking, if the compared value has a remainder when divided by the comparing value and reacting upon that:

```
def __eq__( self, other ):
    if float(other) % self.value > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

That way you can pass in a float that is divisible by self.value(), or the same value as an integer and you return true for all cases where

`int(x) == y || int(x) == int(y) || int(x) == float(y), for all x / y = 1`